# Why printing "" + variables output each variable individually without spacing?

Tags: java

One of my assignments has this code:

```
    System.out.println("" + x + y + count);
```

that outputs the value of x, y and count individually without any spaces. I would like to know more about it online. However, I can't seem to find the right keywords to search it up online. Can someone please explain to me the logic behind this or perhaps point to me a name or keyword for such a situation?

I have always known the " " as a tool to print out a string so I'm confused by this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"" + x + ...` is a way to convert the expression to a string. You could also do `Integer.toString(x) + ...` or `String.valueOf(x) + ...`.

Comment: If you want to have spaces, you have to add spaces: `"" + x + " " + y + " " + count`. Or use formatting for more readability `printf("%d %d %d%n", x, y, count)`.

Comment: Documentation: [String (Java Platform SE 7 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: String concatenation are the proper keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we apply standard Java precedence rules, the statement:

```
System.out.println("" + x + y + count);
```

is equivalent to

```
System.out.println((("" + x) + y) + count);
```

Then we look at the meaning of `+`

- If the static types of *both* `a` *and* `b` are numeric types (either primitive numeric or their boxed types) then `a + b` is numeric addition.
- Otherwise, `a + b` is string concatenation.  The two arguments are converted to strings and the strings are concatenated.

Based on this we can say that all of the `+` operators in the example will be treated as string concatenations.

---

If you want spaces between `x`, `y` and `count` you need to add some string literals; e.g.

```
System.out.println("" + x + " " + y + " " + count);
```

or, more simply:

```
System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + count);
```

---

If you wanted `x`, `y` and `count` to be added (assuming that they are numeric), then you could write this:

```
System.out.println("" + (x + y + count));
```

or, more simply:

```
System.out.println(x + y + count);
```

The latter is using a different overload of `println`.

---

> I have always known the `""` as a tool to print out a string so I'm confused by this.

Ummm ... it is actually an empty string literal.  The usage `"" + x` is simply an *idiom* for converting `x` to a `String`.  The empty string literal has other uses too.  The main one is to represent a String with zero characters.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use String format like this:

```
System.out.printf("%d%d%d", x, y, count);
```

Comment: Perhaps you've meant `%s` and maybe `%s %s %s` to account for the whitespace the OP is looking for?

Comment: I thought thread is try to print "the value of x, y and count individually without any spaces" :D

Answer (score 0):

The `""` is an empty String. In Java when you concatenate a String with other primitives that can be cast to String the result is a String. That means that the code

```
System.out.println("" + something);
```

is a different way to write

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(something));
```

However in your scenario the `"" + x + y + count` means that the elements are converted to String and then concatenated - this means that if `x==1`, `y==2`, `count==3` the result would be `123`. If you wanted to just cast the result to String you would have to indicate that the computation should happen before casting to String for example by using brackets

```
System.out.println("" + (x+y+count));
```

The output of this would be `6`.

Comment: I've changed it to `String::valueOf` to avoid datatype conflicts.

Comment: Should convert them separately... Like: `System.out.println(String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(y) + String.valueOf(count)));`

Comment: Oh I get your point now. I will delete the answer and correct it.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for the heads up. Honestly I completely overlook the fact that it's not in brackets. It's corrected and explained now.